# Robot framework - How to read suite name, test case name along with skip message from report.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I am using "Robot Framework" for my automation testing, if I am facing any functional issues as part of my Automation script execution, I will create a defect and skip that test case by giving the defect number as a skip message(`Skip  Defect#001`). Until that defect is resolved, the affected test script is skipped.

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    BuiltIn


*** Test Cases ***
Custom auto scenarios1
    Skip   Defect_001
    Log   Test1

Custom auto scenarios2
    Log   Test2

Custom auto scenarios3
    Log   Test3

Custom auto scenarios4
    Skip   Defect_002
    Log   Test4
```

[report.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpe4E.png)

I have a requirement where I need to retrieve the following information from `report.html`

1. Skip message (`Defect_001` & `Defect_002`)
2. Skipped Test Case Name (`Custom auto scenarios1` & `Custom auto scenarios4`)
3. Skipped test available Suite name (`Demo`)

Can you please tell me how to retrieve these from `report.html`

Comment: Why the requirement to extract it from report.html? Html can be difficult to parse. Parsing output.xml would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need use robot API and operate on `output.xml` file.

```py
from robot.api import ExecutionResult, ResultVisitor

class Collector(ResultVisitor):

    def visit_test(self, test):
        if test.skipped:
            print(test.name, test.message, test.parent.name)

es = ExecutionResult("output.xml")
collector = Collector()
es.visit(collector)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same information from "report.html" instead "output.xml" ?

Comment: Probably using some headless browser (both report and log file are build using javascript) and later extracting information like from normal page, but it sounds like over-engineering.